# How to build, install and test a release build of Android app using ant

Tags: android, testing, ant

I can build, install and test my applications using the ant commands in the /test project as described in Android documentation here 
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

But I can't find a way to build and install my release build.
It either:
- can't be tested as the certificates don't match (I have configured my test project to have a release build pointing to the same keystore etc), or 
- fails with the error:
  "Cannot run two different modes at the same time. If you are running more than one debug/release/instrument type targets, call them from different Ant calls."

I have tried all combinations of build commants, but can't get an myapp/bin/myapp-release.apk AND test/bin/test-release.apk built and installed to then run tests with.